# Xamarin: Is there any way for my testers to download my app from AppCenter without the need to login to AppCenter First?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

When I used HockeyApp (which is no longer an option), I could just copy the download link to my app and send it to my testers, and when I published a mandatory update to the app on hockeyapp, they got a dialog in the app and pressed Ok, and the app started downloading without the need of being logged in anywhere.

Now that I've migrated to AppCenter, I can't find a way for this to work. What happens now is that when a user opens the app and there is an update to it available, the app opens a browser with a URL to install the app, and requires each tester to login to AppCenter before downloading it. Is there any way to solve this so all users (testers) don't need to create an account at AppCenter now?

This is the only code I use for this atm:

`AppCenter.Start(Constants.Secret, typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute), typeof(Analytics));`

Comment: You can still use the `HockeyApp` mobile app available on Playstore to download the application. But I guess even that requires you to log in

Comment: You can not After November 16, 2019

Comment: Yeah and there is that, I am sure there is no other way though

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/inappupdates
"In-app updates only work for public distribution groups if testers have downloaded the app from their default browser with cookies enabled."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/groups

Check out the documentation, it mentions that you can set "Allow public access" setting for a distribution group and then you'll have a public download link which will not require signing in:

*In addition to this, a public download link is displayed underneath the distribution group name at the top of the distribution group page. Anyone, including testers who aren't explicitly added to the distribution group, can access the release without signing in using the public download link.*

Comment: Thanks! This solved the first part of the problem, much appreciated.

Comment: But when I add a new version of the app it seems like it requires authentication to download it even if the distribution group is set to public. With the "automatic update" from the app and not use the link

Comment: @SomethingElse hmm, maybe it's something with device registration? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/auto-provisioning#app-signing-re-signing-and-device-provisioning

Comment: I found this thread that describes my issue https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

Copying the link of Download button under Distribute/Releases, its working for me to get exact APK directly without going to any group page and download.